# Query Exception in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, sessionfactory

I am using hibernate. I am using the given query to fetch information from db

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select m.menuId,m.menuType,it.itemId,it.name,it.price,it.currency," +
        "ingr.ingredientId,ingr.ingredient from Menu as m, MenuItem as it," +
        "KeyIngredient as ingr where m.menuId  in "+
        "(select MenuId from MenuItem as itm innerjoin KeyIngredient as ing "+ 
        "where itm.itemId = ing.MenuItemId) and m.RestaurantId=" +restaurantId);
```

when i run this query I am getting this error

```
    could not resolve property: menuId of: com.hibernate.model.Menu [select m.menuId,m.menuType,it.itemId,it.name,it.price,it.currency,ingr.ingredientId,ingr.ingredient 
from com.hibernate.model.Menu as m, com.hibernate.model.MenuItem as it,com.hibernate.model.KeyIngredient as ingr where m.menuId  in (select MenuId from 
com.hibernate.model.MenuItem as itm innerjoin KeyIngredient as ing where itm.itemId = 
ing.MenuItemId) and m.RestaurantId=1]
```

This is the menu.hbm.xml file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.hibernate.model.Menu" table="Menu" catalog="mydb">
            <composite-id name="id" class="com.hibernate.model.MenuId">
                <key-property name="menuId" type="int">
                    <column name="menu_id" />
                </key-property>
                <key-property name="restaurantId" type="long">
                    <column name="Restaurant_id" />
                </key-property>
                <key-property name="menuType" type="string">
                    <column name="menuType" length="45" />
                </key-property>
            </composite-id>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Menu Class

```
public class Menu implements java.io.Serializable {

    private MenuId id;

    public Menu() {
    }

    public Menu(MenuId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public MenuId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(MenuId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

MenuId Class

```
public class MenuId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int menuId;
    private long restaurantId;
    private String menuType;

    public MenuId() {
    }

    public MenuId(int menuId, long restaurantId, String menuType) {
        this.menuId = menuId;
        this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
        this.menuType = menuType;
    }

    public int getMenuId() {
        return this.menuId;
    }

    public void setMenuId(int menuId) {
        this.menuId = menuId;
    }

    public long getRestaurantId() {
        return this.restaurantId;
    }

    public void setRestaurantId(long restaurantId) {
        this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
    }

    public String getMenuType() {
        return this.menuType;
    }

    public void setMenuType(String menuType) {
        this.menuType = menuType;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((this == other))
            return true;
        if ((other == null))
            return false;
        if (!(other instanceof MenuId))
            return false;
        MenuId castOther = (MenuId) other;

        return (this.getMenuId() == castOther.getMenuId())
                && (this.getRestaurantId() == castOther.getRestaurantId())
                && ((this.getMenuType() == castOther.getMenuType()) || (this
                        .getMenuType() != null
                        && castOther.getMenuType() != null && this
                        .getMenuType().equals(castOther.getMenuType())));
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;

        result = 37 * result + this.getMenuId();
        result = 37 * result + (int) this.getRestaurantId();
        result = 37 * result
                + (getMenuType() == null ? 0 : this.getMenuType().hashCode());
        return result;
    }

}
```

and this is my entry in the cfg file

```
<mapping resource="com/hibernate/model/Menu.hbm.xml"/>
```

How can I do this properly?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your entity class, Menu, as well?  It sounds like you are using the database ID instead of the property name.

Comment: Posted the classes. Can you figure out something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query looks like SQL rather than HQL. If that's the case, use `session.createSQLQuery()` instead:

```
Query q = session.createSQLQuery("your SQL here");
```

If I'm wrong and it's meant to be HQL, you'll need to post your mappings - it `menu_id` mapped as property?

Comment: I have added more info to the question. Can you please have a look. menu_id was not mapped before but now i changed it, But still having error.

Comment: @Zach your query doesn't make much sense, to be honest - especially the nested subquery. That aside, since `menuId` is part of composite id, you'll have to refer to it as such: `m.id.menuId` rather than `m.menuId`. Same goes for `menuType`

Comment: Ok now I am getting where I went wrong. I am new to hibernate. Your answer createSQLQuery works fine for me. Thanks. I wanted to know how to work with the mapping files thats why I added more info. Thanks  a  lot.

Answer (score 1):

Unresolved properties are just that : java properties which hibernate sees no getters/setters for.

In hibernate, your HQL terms must reference the property in the ".cfg" files --- in the data column names.

Most likely, you meant to query for "menuId", since java beans aren't named with underscores in their getter / Setters.

Comment: I have edited the question to add more information. Could you please have a look. Also I have changed the feilds based getters and setters